# How to make font-awesome caret change from caret-right to caret-down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

The simple code below works if I use **fa-folder** in the i tag and **fa-folder-open** in the javascript, but if I substitute **fa-caret-right** and **fa-caret-down**, it does not work, and I cannot see why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .accordion {
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    .panel {
    display: none;
    }
    .panel.show {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p class="accordion"><i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Building Guides</p>
    <div class="panel">
    <p><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Accessory Structures Building Guide 2012</p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Basement Finish Building Guide 2012</p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Decks Building Guide 2012</p>
    </div>
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    this.firstChild.classList.toggle("fa-folder-open");
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn the right class OFF when you turn the down class ON. Also, I got rid of the non-breaking spaces, and used CSS to render the same result -- cosmetic but way less annoying.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    this.firstChild.classList.toggle("fa-caret-right")
    this.firstChild.classList.toggle("fa-caret-down");
  }
}
```

```css
.fa {
  width: 20px;
}

.accordion {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.panel {
  display: none;
}
.panel.show {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p class="accordion"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Building Guides</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Accessory Structures Building Guide 2012</p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Basement Finish Building Guide 2012</p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Decks Building Guide 2012</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, why would it not matter if I was using the folder icon but matter when using the caret icon?

Comment: Looking into that. It seems they handle the computed attributes differently -- use the dev tools and inspect the elements. Seems to be a matter of which one's rule will be applied. Not really sure how precedence works in this particular case.

Comment: it's because in the folder case, the open folder icon comes later in the CSS stylesheet than the closed folder icon.  So its styles take precedence when it is included.  But the reverse is true for the carets so the right-caret takes precedence over the down-caret even when you include both classes.

Comment: Ah. @andi, you rock. Safest thing to avoid the problem is to toggle OFF one class and toggle ON the other, in every case. Don't count on your CSS to catch mistakes for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're spelling it wrong.
It's **caret** not carat.

Comment: And yeah, that too.